# Getting data in one place from multiple IBM i 's with Crystal reports

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, crystal-reports-2008

We are in talks with a client. I am a Crystal reports developer for one of the locations. They have multiple locations, each with an IBM i.
Each location runs a CR and sends the reports to the COO.

They would like to have all data in one place. 
What I want to know is, Can I run a CR for each place and export the results ( it is same columns) to one excel or Access table, on scheduled basis, then run one CR that will give them all locations in one report, with group on the Location id?

Comment: `They would like to have all data in one place.` - Does this mean they want one **report** or one **database** (or machine)?  Easiest is going to be if everything is on one machine that you run a report over.  You _can_ generate/upload reports on a scheduled basis (via CR or otherwise), but this can be somewhat fragile, comparatively.  Depending on other requirements you may just have the databases act as replication nodes or something...

Comment: it makes more sense to bring all data for the report to one place. Do you happen to know if SSIS can read DB2 data? Or any other way to gather all data into one database for reporting.

Comment: Supposedly it can - you can find tutorials and stuff online - but I've never done it/used it.  There's two ways to share data between databases - either linking them (although that's more often done when you have different datasets altogether), or replication, to put copy data to a different machine.  All major RDBMSs have ways to do both, but it's a major undertaking, from what I understand.